# C# omitting nodes XML

Tags: c#, xml

I have an XML document that is written with this algorithm:

```
public XMLmethod(){
string[] nodes = { "node1", "node2", "node3" }; //etc etc

XmlTextWriter writer= new XmlTextWriter("file.xml", Encoding.UTF8);

writer.WriteStartDocument();
writer.WriteStartElement("root");

foreach (string node in nodes){
writer.WriteStartElement(s);
writer.WriteEndElement();
XMLmethod()}

writer.WriteEndElement();
writer.WriteEndDocument();
}
```

The above is a simplified version. However, I want to be able to filter out some nodes before printing them to xml.

For example:

```
<root>
 <node1>
  <node2> </node2>
  <node3> </node3>
 </node1>
<root>
```

Say I wanted to filter  `<node1> </node1>`

So it would look like this

```
<root>
 <node2></node2>
 <node3></node3>
</root>
```

so it would still want to print the children `<node2></node2>` and `<node3></node3>`

I thought about using an if statement like:

```
foreach (string node in nodes){
if(node == "node1"){}
else{
writer.WriteStartElement(node);
writer.WriteEndElement();
XMLmethod()}
}
```

this successfully doesn't print `<node1>/<node1>` but it also stops it from printing the children nodes. Any idea how I can go about doing this?

Comment: From this code, how do you know that `node2` and `node3` are children of `node1`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a class, such as Foo below, and you want to omit one or more properties when serialzing it using the .Net [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx), use the [XmlIgnore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlignoreattribute.aspx) attribute:

```
public class Foo
{
    [XmlIngore]
    public string Node1 { get; set; }
    public string Node2 { get; set; }
    public string Node3 { get; set; }
}
```

This will cause XmlSerializer to only output `<node2>` and `<node3>`.

Answer (score 0):

If the code that you have posted works, you could probably try removing the items from the list before iterating, for example

```
nodes.Remove("node1");

foreach (string node in nodes)
{
}
```

But, it's unclear from your code sample why you would want to do this. XML documents are nested in a hierarchical manner because it allows for relationships and semantic context between the elements. Removing parent nodes may reduce the usability of the XML you are producing.

For example, if the document was

```
<People>
  <Person>
    <FirstName>Max</FirstName>
    <LastName>Smart</LastName>
  </Person>
</People>
```

It would make no sense to just remove the `<Person>` tag, and output `FirstName` and `LastName` on their own.